# uninitialized constant API::V1::ApplicationSerializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm started using `gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'`. Following [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/getting_started.md) document 
for the implementation.

I have the following relations.

```
landmark has_many concerns
concern belongs_to landmark
concern has_many comments
```

I have created a `ApplicationSerializer` at `app/serializers/api/application_serializer.rb`

```
module API
  class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     # some commode here
  end
end
```

My concern_serializer contains:

```
# ===> Does not work <=====
module API::V1
  class ConcernSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :id, :body
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :landmark

    class CommentSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
      attributes :id, :body
    end

    class LandmarkSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
      attributes :id, :short_address
    end

  end
end


# ====> However, this works <====
module API::V1
  class ConcernSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :id, :body
    has_many :comments

    class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :body
    end

  end
end

# ===> Does not work again<=====
module API::V1
  class ConcernSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :id, :body
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :landmark

    class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :body
    end

    class LandmarkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :short_address
    end

  end
end
```

In the above code if I replace `ApplicationSerializer` with `ActiveModel::Serializer` it works fine but I lose the common code defined in `ApplicationSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an autoloading issue. `ApplicationSerializer` should be in its own file `<serializers directory>/api/application_serializer.rb` (make sure to restart server/spring after creating directories in `app` so that they are picked up by the autoloader)

Also you can refer to it using absolute class name: `::API::ApplicationSerializer`

Comment: I have updated the question. Does not seems like autoloading issue.